# How to know whether login using social account or website login in Django

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I'm develop the site using Django and am using django social_auth API for social login authentication. Here in my website no need to display the change password option when am login using social account. So how to hide that option when am login with social account. OR If there is any possibility to know whether login using social account or website login. Kindly let me know if you have an idea to solve this issue. Thanking you.

Comment: This depends a lot on your implementation of both the authentications. How you are saving the users (users with password and without passwords) ? Are you saving any type of `login flag` along with user info while user logs in?

Comment: I'm using default django user model. Get the information from social account and stored it in user table like username,email,firstname and lastname. I'm using any login flag or with and without password.

Comment: Give an idea how to solve this issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution (when someone don't know the actual implementation) can be

1. Create a new table with `user` as foreign key and one more column with will work as flag for type of authentication.
2. The flag can be `1 for django user` and `2 for social auth user`
3. While creating the user in your system populate this table accordingly.
4. Hide the option of change the password on the basis of same table.

Comment: This looks too overkill for such a simple feature, a session value in a view is enough.

Comment: @omab - Yes, you are right this is overkill for this case, but in future if app will have more type of authentications (like passport, gmail etc) then saving a flag will save lot of calculations and also it removes the dependency on API.

Answer (score 0):

Check the session value `social_auth_last_login_backend`, if it's set it will have the last social backend used to login, if it's not set, then it means that the user logged in with non-social auth.